# SSLHandshakeException Java EE Application with Jasig CAS SSO use Apache mod_jk and Jboss

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss7.x, cas, mod-jk

i have Java EE Application with Jasig CAS SSO.

For login I use URL with services:

```
https://myhost/cas/login?service=https://myhost/myApplication/login_callback_https.html
```

we  use Apache and JBoss.
When I  use Apache mod_proxy its work.
Bud when I use mod_jk, Error come out.

authentication with `https://myhost/cas/login` is succesfuly but 
with service `https://myhost/myApplication/login_callback_https.html`

this Error come out an I hope someone can hep me:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:352)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:45)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:199)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:150)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:826)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1230)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:337)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:333)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
```

Apache and JBoss have the same certificate.

**Apache Configuration:**
**Workers.properties:**

```
worker.list=worker1, jkstatus
worker.jboss60.type=ajp13
worker.jboss60.host=localhost
worker.jboss60.port=8009
worker.jboss60.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
SSLCertificateFile bin/server.crt<br>
SSLCertificateKeyFile bin/server.key<br>
...
JkMount /myApplication/* worker1<br>
JkMount /cas/* worker1<br>
```

**JBoss Configuration in standalone.xml**

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="any" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="any" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    </socket-binding-group>

...
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp" executor="ajp-executor"/>
```

Comment: let us know your operating system and also post mod_jk.log to check the route cause. That will be better if you post your mod_jk.conf file as well

Comment: Seems Ticket Validator is misconfigured, check your filter configuration, url and port.